# Why I can run UI operations in a thread other than main thread in Android?

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin

Previously, I learned that any UI operation must run on the main thread.
Now, why the example below runs without any errors?
Where is the problem?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        Thread {
            findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText).setText("foo")
            findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText).setTextColor(Color.RED)
        }.start()

    }
}
```

Comment: "I learned that any UI operation must run on the main thread" - should, for consistency and to stop "weird stuff" happening. Your code runs because in this specific example Andrroid source code has not checked the calling thread context and not thrown an error and the call stack completes, however many parts of the framework code does check this. Also in some cases Android internally switches thread context using handlers to guarantee thread context.  none of this is given though, hence why all UI operations "should" be performed on the main thread

Answer (score 0):

As developer docs says here:
https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/threads
"If you try to modify or even reference a UI object in a thread other than the main thread, the result can be exceptions, silent failures, crashes, and other undefined misbehavior."
So, it's recommended to do ui operations on the main thread.